# API call providing null response

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, moshi

Note: This is done in Kotlin in Android studio.

Here is the documentation of my API:
[https://www.api-football.com/documentation-v3#tag/Teams/operation/get-teams](https://stackoverflow.com)

I am trying to make a simple call to API-Football using only Retrofit and Moshi. I was expecting back these parameters:

[image: expected params]
However, what I got was this:

[image: error]

Below is the fragment that I am having trouble with TeamsFragment:

```
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.moshi.MoshiConverterFactory

// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"




class Teams Fragment : Fragment() {
// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private var param1: String? = null
private var param2: String? = null
private val retrofit by lazy {
Retrofit.Builder()
.baseUrl("https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/")
.addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
.build()
}
private val apiFootball by lazy { retrofit.create(APIFootball::class.java) }
private val responseText: TextView by lazy { view?.findViewById\<TextView\>(R.id.api_response)!! }

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
arguments?.let {
param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
}
}

override fun onCreateView(
inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
// Inflate the layout for this fragment
val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_teams, container, false)
getTeamData()
return view
}
fun getTeamData() {
apiFootball.getTeams(541).enqueue(object : Callback\<ResponseData\> {
override fun onResponse(
call: Call\<ResponseData\>,
response: Response\<ResponseData\>
) {
responseText.text = response.body().toString()
}

           override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseData>, t: Throwable) {
               responseText.text = t.message
           }
       })

}
companion object {
/\*\*
\* Use this factory method to create a new instance of
\* this fragment using the provided parameters.
\*
\* @param param1 Parameter 1.
\* @param param2 Parameter 2.
\* @return A new instance of fragment TeamsFragment.
\*/
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
@JvmStatic
fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
TeamsFragment().apply {
arguments = Bundle().apply {
putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
}
}
}
}\`
```

Here are my data classes as well VenueResponse and TeamResponse:

```
data class VenueResponse (
  val id: Int,
  val venue_name: String,
  val address: String,
  val venue_city: String,
  val venue_capacity: Int,
  val venue_surface: String,
  val image: String
)
```

```
data class TeamResponse(
  val team_id: Int,
  val name: String,
  val code: String?, //should be null??
  val country: String,
  val imageUrl: String,
  val founded: Int,
  val is_national: Boolean,
  val logo: String
)
```

I tried many different ids and I still did not get any response. I just got TeamResponse(team=null, venue=null). I am at least getting a response back, but it is not at all what I expected and below is the function that I believe is causing the problem:

```
fun getTeamData() {
apiFootball.getTeams(541).enqueue(object : Callback\<ResponseData\> {
override fun onResponse(
call: Call\<ResponseData\>,
response: Response\<ResponseData\>
) {
responseText.text = response.body().toString()
}

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseData>, t: Throwable) {
                responseText.text = t.message
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: You are getting `ResponseData(team=null,venue=null)` as shown in your screenshot, not `TeamResponse(team=null,venu=null)` as state in your text. Also Please take time to clean up your code to be pasted in the post. There are many escaping slashes which make it hard to determine if your code is valid.

Comment: Can you post your `ResponseData` class? Btw, you probably need to use Moshi's Kotlin support: https://github.com/square/moshi/tree/master#codegen